# Get structure size within MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I am wondering how to get the size of a structure at compilation time in MASM.

Here is the C equivalent code.

```c
struct Point
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

printf("Point Stucture size %d\n", sizeof(struct Point));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you'll be declaring the struct in your assembly code.
According to the masm32 documentation you've got the following operators available to you:

```
LENGTHOF variable

SIZEOF variable

SIZEOF type

LENGTH expression

SIZE expression
```

> Description
>
> The `LENGTHOF` operator returns the number of data items allocated for `<variable>`. The `SIZEOF` operator returns the total number of bytes allocated for `<variable>` or the size of `<type>` in bytes. For variables, `SIZEOF` is equal to the value of `LENGTHOF` times the number of bytes in each element.
>
> The `LENGTH` and `SIZE` operators are allowed for compatibility with previous versions of the assembler. When applied to a data label, the `LENGTH` operator returns the number of elements created by the `DUP` operator; otherwise it returns 1. When applied to a data label, the `SIZE` operator returns the number of bytes allocated by the first initializer at the `<variable>` label.
>
> The `LENGTHOF` and `SIZEOF` operators in MASM 6.1 handle arrays much more consistently. These operators return the number of data items and the number of bytes in an initializer.

See masm32.chm in the masm32/help directory.

Answer (score 1):

MASM provides a SIZEOF keyword.

For a Point Structure like the following one:

```
Point STRUCT
x DWORD ?
y DWORD ?
Point ENDS
```

You can use SIZEOF like this.

```
SIZEOF Point
```

`SIZEOF Point` will be replaced by the number 8 in this example.