# Accessing an element of array, which (array) is an element of structure in assembly (MASM)

Tags: arrays, assembly, struct, x86, masm

recently I've started a course on x86 assembly (MASM) and have a question.

I have an array of structs that consist of 2 arrays each

```
Tabl1 struc
    namex db 4 dup (?)
    field1 dw 4 dup (?)
Tabl1 ENDS

Data1 segment
    I_struc db ?
    I_namex db ?
    A1 Tabl1 6 dup (<>)
Data1 ends
```

I need to initialize each element of field1 array of each struct with some kind of value.
How can i access that element using adresses? So far I have

```
Code1 segment
    ASSUME cs:Code1, ds:Data1  
begin:
mov bx, 4
mov cx, 6
loop_1:
    imul I_struc, cx, size Tabl1
    loop_2:
        imul I_namex, bx, size dw
        mov byte ptr A1[I_struc-size Tabl1].field1[I_namex - size dw], somevalue ;line 25
    loop loop_2
loop loop_1

mov ax, 4C00H 
int 21H

Code1 ends
    end begin
```

But MASM compiler says that dw symbol is not defined, although it's a standard type.

[image: Screenshot_1]

Edit 1: If I'm using 2 insted of size dw (which basically is the size of dw type in bytes) I get this error.

[image: Screenshot_2]

Edit 2: using "sizeof dw" insted of "size dw" I get this error

[image: Screen_3]

What I'm doing wrong and what's the solution for that?

Comment: Try using `sizeof` instead of `size`. The syntax of `sizeof` is `SIZEOF variable | type`. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26864321/1305969) may give you some insight.

Comment: @zx485 but there is no variable that i want to find the size of, my goal is to use size of dw type.

Comment: I inferred that you wanted the size of a type, so my previous comment should still be valid.

Comment: @zx485 with sizeof I'm getting "symbol not defined: SIZEOF" error